# How to create local repository for Ubuntu package, that will work with by-hash feature

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, dpkg

I am trying to create a sample repo, which includes a deb file under it.
I used dpkg-scanpackages to create the repo and apt-ftparchive to create the Release file for it

When i try to configure this repo on Ubuntu 14.04 it works fine, apart from one warning that i use SHA1 instead of SHA256, but it gets installed over it

But if i try to do it over ubuntu 16.04 the apt-get command itself fails with "Hash Sum Mismatch" error

I googled it but could not exactly get as to how to create InRelease file or how to actually use the by-hash method that it ask to prefer

Any pointers as in exactly how to create repo that can use this feature will help

Thanks
-G

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I am able to fix my issue.

The problem that I was hitting was because I was using an older version of `apt-ftparchive` and `dpkg-scanpackages`, which only created a MD5 hash, where as 16.04 has forced up SHA256 hash.

Updating my build setup to use the latest binary of `apt-ftparchive` and `dpkg-scanpackages` I was able to successfully create my repo and install the package.